# How to set maximum depth of decision tree for post prunning on matlab?

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

How do I build a tree which has a depth that i want? For example i want to create a decision tree which has a only 3 depth.

```
load ionosphere 
treeModel = fitctree(X,Y) 
view(treeModel) 
view(treeModel,'mode','graph')
```

This code create 7 depth tree. I use same data set but i want to create tree which has 3 or 2 depth. How can I do on matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the maximum depth using the `MaxDepth` name-value pair argument.

Read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitctree.html#namevaluepairarguments) for more details.

```
treeModel = fitctree(X,Y,'MaxDepth',3);
```

Comment: i use matlab version R2015b on Mac OS. I wrote your code before you said,  it occur error: MaxDepth is not a valid parameter name. Do I need to use the new version? R2017b?

Answer (score 0):

Try to be as flexible as possible when building up Matlab environments. Also, as per official documentation, note that the `MaxDepth` option only applies when using `fitctree` on tall arrays.

```
load ionosphere 
treeModel = CreateTreeModel(X,Y,3);
view(treeModel) 
view(treeModel,'mode','graph')

function tm = CreateTreeModel(x,y,depth)
    if (nargin < 3)
        tm = fitctree(x,y);
        return;
    end

    if (depth < 1)
        depth = 1;
    end

    tm = fitctree(x,y,'MaxDepth',depth);
end
```

Comment: i use matlab version R2015b on Mac OS. I wrote your code before you said,  it occur error: MaxDepth is not a valid parameter name. Do I need to use the new version? R2017b?